# PDE for holding a stock

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance, stochastic-differential-equations

Let's suppose we owe an asset and its path is given by the following SDE:
$$ S(t) = A(S, t) dt + B(S, t) d\widetilde{W}$$
where $\widetilde{W}$ is a Brownian motion (under risk neutral measure). 
What is the optimal strategy of selling this asset? What is the value of a portfolio consisting of this single asset?

My understanding is that there is a certain threshold the asset reaches that should trigger the sell. If the value of the portfolio is $V(S(t), t)$ then $$V(x, t) = \widetilde{\mathbb{E}}[e^{-\int_t^{\tau}R(s)ds}S(\tau)]$$
($x = S(t)$, and $\tau$ is a stopping time for the threshold.)

My question: what is the PDE governing $V(x, t)$? How do I get (derive) it? What is the general logic of getting PDEs for american style derivatives? I understand the presentation Shreve gives about linear complementarity conditions in his book "Stochastic calculus for finance, vol II".

Another question (somewhat of a digression): if the SDE is in real world measure, how do we get PDEs? Only by transforming the measure through Girsanov's theorem?

Comment: Your definition of the porfolio value is a bit strange, you are just discounting the asset at the stopping time.

Comment: @Canardini Why is it strange? Isn't it a standard risk neutral valuation?

Comment: What is $V$ then ? What are you trying to value ? I read your formula as the value of receiving the stock at time $\tau$

Comment: @Canardini I agree that with a stock it doesn't make a lot of sense as the discounting should produce the current stock price because of no arbitrage condition. But we can consider S as some general portfolio. Is it reasonable?

Comment: The portfolio will have the same property, you are discounting a tradable asset, therefore is a martingale.